# Which of the scikit learn classification algorithms accept Sparse matrices?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

If I have to use scikit-learn (`sklearn`) library for classification and the feature matrix is a sparse matrix, then which of the classification algorithms of this library can be used by me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this kaggle discussion](https://www.kaggle.com/c/amazon-employee-access-challenge/discussion/5128), the classification algorithms from `scikit-learn` that support sparse matrices are at least:

- `linear_model.LogisticRegression()`
- `svm.SVR()`
- `svm.NuSVR()`
- `naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()`
- `naive_bayes.BernoulliNB()`
- `linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier()`
- `linear_model.Perceptron()`
- `linear_model.Ridge()`
- `linear_model.Lasso()`
- `linear_model.ElasticNet()`
- `linear_model.SGDClassifier()`

Also, from [this quora question](https://www.quora.com/Which-classification-algorithms-in-sklearn-support-sparse-input-matrices), you can check in the implementation of the algorithm if they import `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` .

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @ncasas 's links, Here is the full list of classification/regression/feature selection and few more by David Ziganto's blog. Which I referred last week-

https://dziganto.github.io/Sparse-Matrices-For-Efficient-Machine-Learning/

Also, from sk-learn documentation, they have example code for text classification which is using few of models.

https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html